# Ionic logout not clearing http service data

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

when I click logout button, its changing the state, but not refreshing the page, because of this, my login page text boxes still having entered data. and If i loggIn with new data, Property details http request not pulling the new data.
I tried, $location.path , $state.go but no use, 
can any one help me please.

Login controller

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, AuthenticationService,ClientDetails, $ionicPopup, $state) {

    $scope.data = { clientId: '', lastName: '', email: ''};
    $scope.login = function () {
        AuthenticationService.Login($scope.data.clientId, $scope.data.lastName, $scope.data.email, function(response) {
            if(response.success) {
                ClientDetails.setDetails(response.data);
                $state.go('app.home');
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                $scope.error = response.message;
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: $scope.error
            });
            }
        });
    };
})
```

getting properties through service:

```
.factory('PropertyDetails',
['$http', '$rootScope',
function ( $http, $rootScope) {
    var clientId = $rootScope.globals.clientDetails.ClientId;
    var service = {};
        service.getProperties = function(callback){

            $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var data = ''; var status = ''; var message = '';
            var response = {};
            var Request =  $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://example.com/'+clientId,
                data: data
            })
            Request.success(function(jdata, headers) {
                if( headers === 200 ){
                    if(typeof jdata == 'object'){
                        status = jdata.Status;
                        message = jdata.Message;
                        data = jdata.Data;
                        $rootScope.globals.properties = data;
                    }else{
                        status = false;
                        message = "Response data is not a object!";
                    }
                }else{
                    status = false;
                    message = "Something went wrong!";
                }
                //response = { success : status,  message :  message, data: data };
                response = { success : status,  message :  message, data: $rootScope.globals.properties };
                callback(response);
                //callback($rootScope.globals.properties);
            })
            Request.error(function(data, headers){
                if(typeof data == 'object'){
                    message = data.Message;
                }else{
                    message = "Client not found.";
                }
                response = { success : false,  message :  message };
                callback(response);
            });

        };
        service.clearDetails = function(){
            $rootScope.globals.properties = {};
        };
    return service;
}])
```

My logout controller:

```
.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, ClientDetails, PropertyDetails,$timeout,$ionicHistory, $state,$location){
$scope.logOut = function(){
    ClientDetails.clearDetails();
    PropertyDetails.clearDetails();
    $timeout(function () {
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({ disableBack: true, historyRoot: true });
    $state.go('login');
    }, 30);
}
```

})

Thank you

Comment: Did you fix this already? Next time you should post your template HTML as well, because it can probably be an incorrect two-way data binding that's causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

Many Way to clear textbox first of controller call one time to load in ionic if you want to reload again data you used

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
 //here some code 
 });
```

above code when  you open page this code is running every time[load controller].
its simple way.